# EJB2.x container managed relationship

Tags: ejb-2.x

I am a total novice to EJB technologies, so recently I started learning EJB3.0, when reading through books/online resources, I found lot of references and comparisons to EJB2.0 and how EJB3.0 simplifies things by requiring developer to create fever components. I left my reading of EJB3.0 and started reading EJB2.0. I started with book "Enterprise Java Beans by Richard Monson-Haefel III Edition", its pretty old edition (2000) but is very comprehensive. I understood the things pretty well until container managed relationship. I found that through abstract persistence model (abstract accessor methods) and abstract schema (deployment descriptor), a relationship is established between two entity beans. Also I found that for persistence fields of entity bean, at the time of deployment a mapping is established between virtual persistent field and actual database table column. When do such mapping is established for virtual relationship field, is it at the time of deployment only? 
**Uni-directional one to one**

```
    <ejb-jar>
<enterprise-beans>
    <entity>
        <ejb-name>CustomerEJB</ejb-name>
        <home>com.titan.customer.CustomerHomeRemote</home>
        <remote>com.titan.customer.CustomerRemote</remote>
        <ejb-class>com.titan.customer.CustomerBean</ejb-class>
        <persistence-type>Container</persistence-type>
        <prim-key-class>java.lang.Integer</prim-key-class>
        <reentrant>False</reentrant>
        <cmp-version>2.x</cmp-version>
        <abstract-schema-name>Customer</abstract-schema-name>
        <cmp-field><field-name>id</field-name></cmp-field>
        <cmp-field><field-name>lastName</field-name></cmp-field>
        <cmp-field><field-name>firstName</field-name></cmp-field>
        <primkey-field>id</primkey-field>
        <security-identity><use-caller-identity/></security-identity>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <ejb-name>AddressEJB</ejb-name>
        <local-home>com.titan.address.AddressHomeLocal</local-home>
        <local>com.titan.address.AddressLocal</local>
        <ejb-class>com.titan.address.AddressBean</ejb-class>
        <persistence-type>Container</persistence-type>
        <prim-key-class>java.lang.Integer</prim-key-class>
        <reentrant>False</reentrant>
        <cmp-version>2.x</cmp-version>
        <abstract-schema-name>Address</abstract-schema-name>
        <cmp-field><field-name>id</field-name></cmp-field>
        <cmp-field><field-name>street</field-name></cmp-field>
        <cmp-field><field-name>city</field-name></cmp-field>
        <cmp-field><field-name>state</field-name></cmp-field>
        <cmp-field><field-name>zip</field-name></cmp-field>
        <primkey-field>id</primkey-field>
        <security-identity><use-caller-identity/></security-identity>
    </entity>
</enterprise-beans>
<relationships>
    <ejb-relation>
        <ejb-relation-name>Customer-Address</ejb-relation-name>
        <ejb-relationship-role>
            <ejb-relationship-role-name>Customer-has-an-Address</ejb-relationship-role-name>
            <multiplicity>One</multiplicity>
            <relationship-role-source>
                <ejb-name>CustomerEJB</ejb-name>
            </relationship-role-source>
            <cmr-field>
                <cmr-field-name>homeAddress</cmr-field-name>
            </cmr-field>
        </ejb-relationship-role>
        <ejb-relationship-role>
            <ejb-relationship-role-name>Address-belongs-to-Customer</ejb-relationship-role-name>
            <multiplicity>One</multiplicity>
            <relationship-role-source>
                <ejb-name>AddressEJB</ejb-name>
            </relationship-role-source>
        </ejb-relationship-role>
        </ejb-relation>
</relationships>
</ejb-jar>
```

In Unidirectional relationship Customer EJB has relationship field homeAddress. In the database table CUSTOMER has a column ADDRESS_ID. When do the mapping between homeAddress & ADDRESS_ID is established.

Also for bi-directional relationship fields where both relationship roles have  element defined in deployement descriptor but in the actual database table only one table holds the foreign key (in case of many-one and one-may), do we need to map  from other relationship role to any column?

Bi-directional one-to-one

```
<relationships>
    <ejb-relation>
    <ejb-relation-name>Customer-CreditCard</ejb-relation-name>
    <ejb-relationship-role>
        <ejb-relationship-role-name>Customer-has-a-CreditCard</ejb-relationship-role-name>
        <multiplicity>One</multiplicity>
        <relationship-role-source>
            <ejb-name>CustomerEJB</ejb-name>
        </relationship-role-source>
        <cmr-field>
        <cmr-field-name>creditCard</cmr-field-name>
        </cmr-field>
    </ejb-relationship-role>
    <ejb-relationship-role>
        <ejb-relationship-role-name>CreditCard-belongs-to-Customer</ejb-relationship-role-name>
        <multiplicity>One</multiplicity>
        <relationship-role-source>
            <ejb-name>CreditCardEJB</ejb-name>
        </relationship-role-source>
        <cmr-field>
        <cmr-field-name>customer</cmr-field-name>
        </cmr-field>
    </ejb-relationship-role>
    </ejb-relation>
</relationships>
```

Customer EJB has relationship field creditCard, While CreditCard EJB has relationship field customer. In database CUSTOMER table has column CREDITCARD_ID while CREDIT_CARD table has column CUSTOMER_ID. Is it required for CUSTOMER table to have a CREDITCARD_ID column. Is it always necessary for abstract schema to map exactly to the database schema? Is this relationship established at deployment time?

Comment: sorry, is going to be really difficult that somebody around here be interested into this old and deprecated subject

Comment: okay, may be I'll find it out myself once I try couple of hands on exercies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the mapping from CMP metadata to DB tables happens at deploy time using vendor-specific tools.  From the EJB 3.0 specification:

> The EJB deployment descriptor for EJB 2.1 entity beans describes
>   logical relationships among entity beans. It does not provide a
>   mechanism for specifying how the abstract persistence schema of an
>   entity bean or of a set of interrelated entity beans is to be mapped
>   to an underlying database. This is the responsibility of the Deployer,
>   who, using the Container Provider’s tools, uses the logical
>   relationships that are specified in the deployment descriptor to map
>   to the physical relationships that are specific to the underlying
>   resource.

Comment: Thanks bkail for your response. I got my answer.